# Amazon RDS SQL Server instance: limits?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

Where I can read about what limitations and restrictions are in RDS SQL Server?

I.e. at least: are available these features?

```
1. Service Broker services and queues
2. SQLCLR functions, procedures, user types
3. Full-Text indexes and search
4. Extended stored procedures
5. (MAX)-types like varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX) etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this document of AWS RDS for SQL Server: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

Comment: Thank you. There is nothing about user's extended stored procedures. Can I add and use my xps?